# bash: /usr/bin/apt-get: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal, apt-get

I'm having a few issues. I'm using Kali Linux. In the terminal, I attempted to do 
`apt-get update` but I'm getting this message back,

> 'bash: /usr/bin/apt-get: cannot execute binary file: Exec format
>   error'

It started having this issue when I attempted to install Visual Studio Code via terminal command `dpkg -i code_1.41.1-1576681836_amd64.deb`. Although the vscode icon shows up in 'Accessories', once I try to open the program, it doesn't open. So I attempted to do the `apt-get update` just in case something was being missed. Any help would be greatly appreciated.